# Nginx add specific prefix if not exist in URL

Tags: nginx, redirect, url-rewriting, nginx-location

I have lots of URLs like

```
https://www.example.com/some-random-page1
https://www.example.com/test/some-random-page2
https://www.example.com/test/some-random-page3
https://www.example.com/some-random-page4
https://www.example.com/some-random-page5
```

I want to add prefix "test" in those URLs which have not test prefix like

```
https://www.example.com/some-random-page1
```

will be redirect to

```
https://www.example.com/test/some-random-page1
```

How can I achieve this in nginx?